# ftp shell script can't copy directory into remoteDir

Tags: shell, ftp

I have a shell script about uploading files below:

```
remodir="(Skip)"
host="(Skip)"
USER="(Skip)"
PASSWD="(Skip)"
localDir="(Skip)"
ftp -n $host <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
prompt
lcd $localDir
cd $remodir
epsv4 off
passive
mput *
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

it can copy localDir files to remodir
but it can't copy localDir directory to remodir

Comment: You can't `put` a directory, only files

Comment: "ncFtp" can upload files recursively but normal ftp cannot. You can download "ncFtp" software from http://www.ncftp.com/download/ .